# Mongoid query's equal operator

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongoid

I want to get the first 42 years old person in my database.

How can i make this query works :

```
Person.where(:Age.eq => 42).first
```

Instead of getting the query's result, I got :

```
undefined method `eq' for :Age:Symbol
```

Comment: Person.where(Age: 42).first

Comment: If not exist then try this so it will create and return: Person.where(Age: 42).first_or_create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it:-

```
Person.where(:age => 42).first
```

It will query the `Person` having `age = 42`

OR

Query in this way:-

```
Person.find_by age: 42
```

The find_by method finds the first record matching with this condition

[See the documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html)

Answer (score 0):

What about just :

```
Person.where(Age: 42).first
```

?